# HIghcharts Scrollbar (w/ showFull false) displays after setExtremes called

Tags: highcharts, scrollbar

After setting the extremes of a graph to dataMin and dataMax on the xAxis the xAxis scrollbar that is configured with showFull false still displays.

Background on how we get in this state:
We have a chart that gets updated data every 30 seconds, instead of redrawing we use chart.update w/ series attribute and redraw false.
this updates the dataMin dataMax attributes of the axis but not the min/max attributes (which control the window in view)

using logic to determine if we want to interrupt the users work flow we decide if it is necessary to call setExtremes w/ redraw true
-- NOTE: this is mainly required because otherwise the graph min can be bellow the dataMin for the axis (causing whitespace)
using floor and setExtremes i am able to partially resolve that problem by pushing the window in view to the updated time range and using floor to prevent them from scrolling back (tho this is sub par since the whitespace clearly still exists and can be 'seen' in the scrollbar styling)

HOWEVER even w/ setExtremes dataMin dataMax the scrollbar is still shown

Expected: graph is updated with more recent live data, window of time range in view for graph is updated IFF the min would otherwise be lower than the new dataMin, scrollbar should now see 'universe' as newDataMin - newDataMax (! oldDataMin - newDataMax which seems to be the case)

Actual: graph is updated with more recent data, window of time is not update automatically, Time that is no longer covered by query is now represented by ugly white space

EDIT:

```
void handleLiveUpdate(List agentSeries, int rangeStartTime) {
  // Needed to decide down the line if we should redraw graph
  var xAxisExtremesPreUpdate = chart["xAxis"][0].callMethod("getExtremes");

  // Updates the chart's data w/o forcing the graph to redraw itself
  // Updates the XAxis dataMin && dataMax attributes BUT NOT the min max attributes
  // (where the min/max attributes determine the window of time in view for the chart)
  chart.callMethod("update", [new js.JsObject.jsify({
    'series': agentSeries
  })]);

  // Decide if redrawing the graph would be disruptive or if it is required
  var xAxisExtremesPostUpdate = chart["xAxis"][0].callMethod("getExtremes");
  if (xAxisExtremesPreUpdate['max'] == xAxisExtremesPreUpdate['dataMax']
      && xAxisExtremesPreUpdate['min'] == xAxisExtremesPreUpdate['dataMin']) { /* Full View Case */
    // Keep entire TimeRange in view as window moves
    chart["xAxis"][0].callMethod("setExtremes", [xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['dataMin'], xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['dataMax'], true, true]);
//TODO scrollbar still visible.. why ? 
  } else { /* Partial View Case */
    // Gather data on current extremes after updating the series.data
    var min = xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['min'];
    var max = xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['max'];
    var range = max - min;
    // Determine which partial view case we are in
    // 'Left Aligned' the min value before change was the dataMin before change
    // 'Right Aligned' the max value before change was the dataMax before change
    // 'Not Aligned' the min/max values do not correlate to the dataMin/dataMax values - indicates user had scrolled to some custom portion of time range
    if (xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['min'] < xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['dataMin']) { /* Partial View - Left Aligned (Ex looking at first hour of last 8 hours) */
      min = xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['dataMin'];
      max = min + range;
      chart["xAxis"][0].callMethod("setExtremes", [min, max, true, true]);
    } else if (xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['max'] == xAxisExtremesPreUpdate['dataMax']) { /* Partial View - Right Aligned (Ex looking at most recent week of last month) */
      max = xAxisExtremesPostUpdate['dataMax'];
      chart["xAxis"][0].callMethod("setExtremes", [max - range, max, true, true]);
    } else { /* Partial View - Not Aligned (Extremes do not touch dataMin dataMax => no need to redraw as window moves s*/
      // NO-OP: no need to redraw since moving window has no impact on window in view
    }
  }

  // Always update the floor attribute, prevents long lived charts from scrolling back to a time they no longer have data in hand for
  chart["xAxis"][0].callMethod("update", [new js.JsObject.jsify({
    'floor': rangeStartTime
  }), true]);
}
```

EDIT 2: screenshots for illustration

W/ Current solution
[image: note that scrollbar has space on left to move even though there is no data there - why is this the case?, Note 2: even when full chart in view and kept in view the scrollbar stays in view]

W/ Solution Commented Out
[image: without the solution after calling chart update series then the dataMin doesn't seem to be updated and therefore white space is created]

JSFiddle Note: update there seems to update the xAxis as i would have expected.

Comment: Hi @Poncher, Could you reproduce this issue in some online code editor? It would be much easier to help you.

Comment: @ppotaczek i can give it a go - my first stab at making a jsfiddle produced the expected result of updating the dataMin/dataMax appropriately - i hadn't anticipated needing special logic to move as i update the data - here is the jsfiddle i'm attempting to recreate the problem in https://jsfiddle.net/bo8eL42v/16/

Comment: took some screenshots for illustrative purposes

Comment: Poncher - Let's try to simplify the situation a bit. You want to hide the scrollbar after changing extremes to dataMin/dataMax, right? Does this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ajy82szf/ illustrate your problem? Let's try to simplify the situation a bit. You want to hide the scrollbar after changing extremes to dataMin/dataMax, right? Does this example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/ajy82szf/ illustrate your problem?

Comment: Yes 100%, after updating the series and then updating the extremes i would have assumed the dataMin dataMax would be set appropriately and that the scrollbar would disappear since we would effectively be viewing the fullrange

Comment: Sorry for the double comment!

Comment: not a problem at all - Thank you for helping out on multiple of my highcharts tickets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `setExtremes` method, you should update the axis with `min` and `max` properties:

```
chart.xAxis[0].update({
    min: chart.xAxis[0].dataMin,
    max: chart.xAxis[0].dataMax
});
```

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/y150hupz/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#update

Comment: That did it! can you explain why this method worked when it purports to do the same thing? also is there a way i could have found out that update > setExtremes in this case on my own ?

Comment: Because in this case the `update` method recreate the axis . For more information, you can check the source code: https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.src.js